# I have cheap phone (apparently) working on Android 7.1, I wish to erase everything to the hardware level and load the phone with a fresh OS

Tags: rooting, hardware, 7.1-nougat

**Background:**

I have a USD $30 Chinese Android Phone made by a company called BlackZone, I have never heard of the company, the phone comes loaded with Android 7.1 Nougat which i believe is a little too fishy since it is nothing like the Nougat versions i have used and the storage shows folders with Chinese names which have permissions to access all data including location SIM information Network Information (seems to have root privilege). I think the hardware is usable though. I wish to erase everything from the phone to the hardware level and rebuild the phone using a verified version of Android. I have never worked in this domain before and do not know the way forward other than rooting the phone which also doesnt seem to be working. Could you fine people teach and guide me in the way forward.

**Required Help**

1.root the phone. (i have tried Kingo root, doesnt seem to be working)

2.Remove OS and Kernels

3.Reconfigure kernels and the ports available

4.Reinstall OS

P.S - it would also help if you could guide me to appropriate tags so that this question may reach the actual target audiance.

I am open to providing any and all information required.

Comment: Just so you know, "loading" Android on a device is nothing like loading Windows onto a PC: Android often has locked bootloaders to prevent any tampering in the first place; the OS isn't universal to all hardwares so you need to make a build yourself that specifically targets your device (which then requires open-source drivers and hardware knowledge). It's not like you can throw a "universal", clean Android build onto it, make small adjustments and it will run flawlessly (if at all) - at least not yet.